# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' on Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been looking at other similar questions and changed everything they said..
But the error still persists since i have updated my Android Studio to 2.0
If anybody can help !

In Gradle scrips i have two gradle files :-

build.gradle(Project:My Project)

build.gradle(Module:app)

build.gradle(Project:My Project) -- this file Looks like this

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and the other build.gradle(Module:app) -- this file looks like this

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "supportcom.a593038.androidsuppoprtlibrary"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first file remove this line:

> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```